# ¿Como detectar cuando el cursor de texto se activa?

Tags: javascript, html

Lo que quiero hacer es que cuando se le dé click a un elemento se haga editable y si se le vuelve a dar click ya no sea editable, pero  si se activa el cursor para añadir texto que no se vuelva no editable, tengo esto:

Html:

```
<div class="element"></div>
```

Js:

```
const element = document.getElementsByClassName("element")[0];
element.addEventListener("click", on_click);
function on_click(){
    if(element.contentEditable=="true"){
        element.contentEditable="false";
        return;
    }
    element.contentEditable="true";
}
```

Lo que pasa esque si le doy click automáticamente no puedo escribir en el y cuando le doy click en el elemento para poder escribir ya se me vuelve ineditable, lo que quiero es detectar si el cursor de texto está activado, y si esta no se vuelva ineditable. ¿existe alguna función para detectar cuando se activa el cursor del texto? Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

para hacerme la vida sencilla lo que yo haría sería usar `ondblclick` (on double click) en vez de `onclick` y solo por mejor experiencia de usuario agrego el borde cuando sea editable

```js
function makeEditable(x) {
    const thisElem = document.getElementById(x); 
  if (thisElem.contentEditable == 'true') {
    thisElem.contentEditable = 'false';
    thisElem.style.border = 'none'
  } else {
    thisElem.contentEditable = 'true';
    thisElem.style.border = '1px solid #aaa'
  } 
}
```

```css
.not-selectable {
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1" class="not-selectable" ondblclick="makeEditable(this.id)">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
<div id="div2" class="not-selectable" ondblclick="makeEditable(this.id)">Cum sequi enim aut perspiciatis aspernatur</div>
<div id="div3" class="not-selectable" ondblclick="makeEditable(this.id)">non distinctio temporibus a rerum</div>
<div id="div4" class="not-selectable" ondblclick="makeEditable(this.id)">aspernatur eum nihil galisum et consequuntur nemo?</div>
```